# if else condition with math/big

Tags: if-statement, go

I'm trying to do comparisons on big numbers but can only get a the string value.
So how do you do a condition on a `big.Int`. Below is the closest to what I have tried.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {

    dirtyVal := "9446744073709551615"
    dv := big.NewInt(0)
    dv.SetString(dirtyVal, 10)
    userVal := dv.String()

    maxVal := "18446744073709551615"
    mv := big.NewInt(0)
    mv.SetString(maxVal, 10)
    // maxValue := mv.String()

    if userVal > maxVal {
        fmt.Println("True")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("False")
    }

}
```

Comment: You can use `if dv.Cmp(mv)>0` to compare two big.Int

Comment: @siritinga i have used "Cmp()" it but was unsure, thank you

Comment: Working with big.Int is a bit tricky, yes. I had some issues when chaining operations, it is easier to write one operation per line, much more easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `func (*Int) Cmp` to compare two big.Int http://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Cmp

```
if dv.Cmp(mv)>0 {
    fmt.Println("True")
} else {
    fmt.Println("False")
}
```